# How to resolve promise once we get response from api call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, axios

I have method dropDowndata that is being called on page load and it is rendering dropdownbData so in `getClientList` i got the response from api call however when i am trying to call `getCLientList`in `dropdDownData` it shows Promise is pending and that result in undefined `data`. what is implemented wrong in below code ? How to resolve axios promise ?

main.js

```
function dropdDowndata() {
        var _env = getEnv();
        var data;
        getClientList().then(function(response) {
          data = response;
        });

};

function getClientList = function() {
    debugger;
    var resetResponse = "";
    var refId = GUIDUtil.Guid.newGuid().toString("N");
    var details = {};
    var params = {
        "Request": {
            "header": {
                "serviceContext": {
                    "apiVersion": "1.0",
                    "lineOfBusiness": "SPD"
                },
                "securityContext": {
                    "securityType": "apiKey",
                    "apiKey": "26283629239362127"
                }
            },
            "details": details
        }
    };
    var clientListParams = {
        url: getHostName() + '/test/client',
        data: params,
        method: 'POST',

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    return axios(clientListParams).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;

    }).catch(error);
};
```

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1)

Comment: What's `function getClientList = function() {` ?? It should be `var getClientList = function() {` i dont see  anything wrong in code other than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the *Promise* to the variable `data`, not its result. You can either use async/await to wait for the resolution, or handle things inside the `.then` callback.

```
async function dropdDowndata() {
        var _env = getEnv();
        var data = await getClientList();
        // Do processing of data here...
};
```

Comment: Thank you i was looking for this solution!